# How do I make Github's Git Shell appear in Windows 10 search?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, search, git-shell

I'm trying to get the Git Shell (from GitHub) to appear as a search result in the Windows 10 search bar. It shows up under "All Apps" and I can even pin it to the menu, but it won't appear in search. The Git Shell shortcut itself launches the powershell with some specific arguments, so it's not a normal .exe, presumably why Windows is ignoring it. Any idea how to fix this? It may seem like a small thing, but I open most of my apps through search, and it keeps throwing me off.

Comment: FYI, it is possible to pin the shortcut as a tile, but it still won't show up in search.

Comment: To add some detail for those who may be able to answer but don't use git shell:

gitshell is a shortcut to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem.  I ended up solving it in two steps:

1. Create a batch file which launches Git Shell.
2. Make a shortcut for the batch file, and add the shortcut to the Start Menu

### Batch file to launch Git Shell

My batch file launcher is named `posh-git.bat`:

```
@echo off

set GH_APP=%LOCALAPPDATA%\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms
set GH_OPT=--open-shell

if exist "%GH_APP%" goto :haveapp
echo "%GH_APP%" not found
goto :eof

:haveapp
start "dummy" /b "%GH_APP%" %GH_OPT%

:eof
set GH_APP=
set GH_OPT=
```

I put it in my `~\bin` folder (which I added to my PATH), but this isn't critical.  You just need a file that you can make a shortcut to.

### Create a shortcut and add it to the Start Menu

1. Find the `posh-git.bat` file in a File Explorer window.
2. Right-click the batch file.  Choose "Create Shortcut"
3. Rename the new shortcut.  I recommend naming it **Git Shell**
4. Add the shortcut to your Start Menu.
   For me, the **GitHub** desktop app already has a link at
   `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\GitHub, Inc`
   so I added my new **Git Shell** shortcut into that same folder.

Now I can open the start menu and type "git shell", and the search finds my start menu program and allows me to launch it.